# F# - Convert Int option to Int64 option

Tags: f#

Is there better way how to do this? :

```
let intOption = Some(123) 
let longOption = match intOption with
                   | Some x -> Some(int64 x )
                   | None   -> None
```

I need to convert `option of int` to `option of int64`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Option.map` does exactly what you need.

```
intOption |> Option.map int64
```

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is [`Option.map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/option.map%5B%27t,%27u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D):

```
let longOption = Option.map int64 intOption
```